# In the second sentence I need passive voice (about being born, is it right?)

Tags: grammar

> Our homeland mostly affects on our personality. We become a nation automatically, just by being born. And differences between nationalities, traditions, lifestyles, cultures etc. makes us want to travel.
>
> [(Source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRr1e.png)

in the second sentence i need passive voice (about being born, is it right?) thank you so much for attention and help (i hope). have a nice day

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please edit your question by typing in the text in question rather then using an image. It will surely get a prompt reply. Check out https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour  for more tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Being born" is a passive, but we don't think of it like that.  Instead it is just a verb phrase.  In particular "I was born by someone" is correct, but unusual. You can use it like other verbs, and you can form gerunds "being born". There is no problem there.

The trouble is how you use "we"  You say "We are born" (referring to individuals) and  "We become a nation".  But this sounds like "Each individual becomes a nation". You should think about rephrasing to change the part about "We become a nation" to "We join a nation" or "We are assigned a nation" or similar. You can choose the best word.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bear) definition of bear:

> to give birth to young, or (of a tree or plant) to give or produce fruit or flowers

So, we say

> A mother bears a child - *active voice*
>   A child is born [by its mother] - *passive voice*

If you are talking about something from the child's perspective rather than the mother's, you have to use passive voice.